# TypeScript function accepting only arrays of objects which have property specified by other parameter and this property is numeric

Tags: typescript

```
function findRow<T = string>(
    table: {
        [k: T]: number;
        [k: string]: unknown;
    }[],
    value: number,
    field: T
): typeof table[number] | null {
    for (let i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
        let x = table[i][field];
        if (Math.abs(x - value) < 0.01) {
            return table[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The idea is that function should only accept arrays of objects as the 1st parameter where objects have property specified in 3rd parameter and this property is numeric. Please suggest correct typing.

Example usages of this functions:

```
const OBJECTS = [
  { a: 1, b: 'first' },
  { a: 2, b: 'second' },
];
findRow(OBJECTS, 2.005, 'a'); // OK, returns second row
findRow(OBJECTS, 5, 'a'); // OK, returns null
findRow(OBJECTS, 1.005, 'b'); // Not OK, should display TS error because property 'b' is not numeric
```

In other words, array in 1st parameter may contain objects with any properties but it is required to have numeric property specified as a string in the 3rd parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would recommend using a helper type to extract keys which map to values of type `number`. Such a type can be written, for example, like so:

```
type NumberValuedKeysOf<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends number ? K : never;
}[keyof T];
```

Then, you can simplify the signature of your function by using that utility, instead of trying to capture that restriction in the generic. So for example:

```
function findRow<T extends Record<string, any>>(table: T[], value: number, field: NumberValuedKeysOf<T>): T { /* ... */ }
```

Using that signature, we seem to get your desired inferences:

```
const OBJECTS = [
  { a: 1, b: 'first' },
  { a: 2, b: 'second' },
];

findRow(OBJECTS, 2.005, 'a'); // OK, returns second row
findRow(OBJECTS, 5, 'a'); // OK, returns null
findRow(OBJECTS, 1.005, 'b'); // Argument of type '"b"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"a"'.
```

Comment: There is a problem: the function accepts array where one of the objects has non-numeric 'a' property, like:

findRow(
    [
        { a: 1, b: 'first' },
        { a: 2, b: 'second' },
        { a: '3', b: 'third' },
    ],
    2.005,
    'a'
);